# Search in Google Map v2 with marker

Tags: search, dictionary, fragment, marker, geocode

How Can I Geocode/Search a location or a certain place/point in Google Maps V2 Map Fragment
and then,place a marker on that point of the mapfragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 here http://vdw.staytuned.gr/get-coordinates-of-google-map-draggable-marker-using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/ and then go here https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 so you can save your data's in your database